# Prove That $\sin(1)+\sin(2)+...+\sin(n)=\frac{\sin(\frac{n+1}{2})\sin(\frac{n}{2})}{\sin(\frac{1}{2})}"$

Tags: trigonometry, induction

I need help **Proving** this: "For Every $n\in \mathbb{N-{0}}$ Prove the following:

$$\sin(1)+\sin(2)+...+\sin(n)=\frac{\sin(\frac{n+1}{2})\sin(\frac{n}{2})}{\sin(\frac{1}{2})}"$$

I assume we have to use Induction On this but I failed to do so

If anyone can provide a simple and clear proof I would be grateful!

Comment: Use the de Moivre's identity $e^{i k x}= \cos(k x)+i\sin(k x)$ giving $\sum_k e^{i k x}$

Comment: Is there no other way of proving this other than with complex numbers?

Comment: You can use induction.

Comment: I failed to demonstrate it using induction...

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Remember to show your work on the problem. Otherwise it looks like you are asking others to do your homework for you. You said you failed trying to prove it by induction, show what you did, where did you get stuck, so we can help you.

Comment: @ssuag I was writing my answer when the question was closed. This is what I wrote https://imgur.com/Bm7DlEy

Comment: @Raffaele I'm sorry for that, your image link isn't working for me

Comment: Try this https://ibb.co/w4w0Vjk  @ssuag

Comment: I'm very grateful, exactly how I tried proving it and got stuck, Thank you so much!@Raffaele

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**:

You don't need induction. Simply use that

$$\sin(1)+\sin(2)+\dots+\sin(n)=\operatorname{Im}\bigl(\mathrm e^{i}+\mathrm e^{2i}+\dots+\mathrm e^{ni}\bigr),$$
which is the sum of a geometric series with common ratio $\mathrm e^{i}$.